# Angular unit test to check if CSS class has been added to DOM element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, unit-testing

I have an ng-repeat which produces a number of DOM elements:

```
    <div "class_{{$index}}" ng-click="checkType(type, $index);"ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
```

When clicking between the first two elements I want to toggle an *active* class between them, so I'm doing the following, I know `addClass` and `removeClass` are not really the proper Angular way of doing things, but this is working ok for me at the moment.

```
    $scope.checkType = function(m, n){

        if(m == 'type one'){
            $('.class_0').addClass('be_active');
            $('.class_1').removeClass('be_active');
        }

        if(m == 'type two'){
            $('.class_1').addClass('be_active');
            $('.class_0').removeClass('be_active');
        }
    }
```

My question is, **can I write an Angular Unit Test to check if the classes have been properly added / removed?**

Comment: `class_{{$index}}` should probably be `class="class_{{$index}}"` or `ng-class="class_{{$index}}"`

Comment: @Magicprog.fr copy and paste error there, fixed.